# How do you make paths and apply brush strokes simultaneously in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, brush

I want to be able to draw with the paintbrush and create a path at the same time.

Here is an image to show what I would like to do:

[image]

The artist in the image above is able to draw a brush stroke while creating a path at the same time. When I try this I get a simple black line and instead of "path" in the upper left corner of the screen my screen reads "no selection." What settings do I need to change to be able to do this? I found this resource on Adobe's help page but all it really says is "draw a line like normal and you will have a path" but that isn't the case for me (https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html#draw_paths_and_apply_brush_strokes_simultaneously).

Thank you for any one who can help! I've been searching all over and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: You actually are creating paths; you just may not know it because the default for the brush is not to select the path once you've drawn it. If you select the Brush tool, hit the enter key, and make sure "Keep Selected" is checked, is that the behaviour you're hoping for?

Comment: @GeoffBall yes that makes sense. I guess I was confused because he manages to select the path automatically upon release (the image was taken from a video) and I'm trying to figure out how to do that so I can copy his workflow. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that all I had to do was double click the brush in the tools panel and check "keep selected" in the brush options panel. Photo below.[image]